# Change varchar column to datetime?

Tags: php, mysql

I have column in mysql table called "dtm"
Data in it is like this "20200525/0704Z"
It has date and time in Zulu format.
Currently column type is varchar 255.

How do I convert this to more useful column type like datetime?

Im getting "too big precision error max is 6" when trying to just change column type.
Thanks

Comment: Create a new column

Comment: code your way out, presuming you not changed entire codebase which expects that format.. make column `dtmtmp` etc with datetime.. make a 5-10ish line script which loops over fixes format and adds to the column,  delete old column and code rename new col, make coffee..

Comment: Please mark Calvin's answer as accepted, as I said mine is only an addition to his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An addendum to @Calvin-Tan's answer since it would be a poor fit in the comment section.

You can populate the new column from the old directly in MySQL using a query like:

```sql
UPDATE table SET new_date = CONCAT(
  SUBSTR(old_date, 1, 4),
  '-',
  SUBSTR(old_date, 5, 2),
  '-',
  SUBSTR(old_date, 7, 2),
  ' ',
  SUBSTR(old_date, 10, 2),
  ':',
  SUBSTR(old_date, 12, 2),
  ':00'
);
```

Which will reformat the string as `2020-05-25 07:04:00`.

Also bear in mind that MySQL date/time types have *no concept of timezone*.

Answer (score 6):

You are better off creating a second column with a datetime datatype. Then use php to convert the old dtm format and update it into its new datetime column, before finally deleting the old dtm column.